# Does "its" relate to the old generation or the new generation in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> At the same time, people will not retire at sixty-five and will not make way for the new generation with **its** novel ideas and aspirations.

Does *its* relate to the old generation or the new generation? What do I say if I want *its* to mean the opposite?

Comment: Which generation do you think has "novel ideas and aspirations"?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "its" refers to the new generation. Moreover, there's no way you can make "its" refer to "people", since "people" is plural. And even if you used "their", instead of "its", you'd have to rephrase the sentence, maybe to something like this:

> At the same time, people will not retire at sixty-five, with their novel ideas and aspirations, and will not make way for the new generation.

Anyway, as @ThePhoton suggested, this sentence would make no sense, since it's the new generation that's supposed to have novel ideas and aspirations.